# can we build ASP.NET MVC based on MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

Can we build ASP.NET MVC based on MYSQL database?

if yes, is there any article availabe?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asp.net MVC doesn't force you to use any specific kind of data access. You can use any database you want, provided you have a way to access it from .NET of course.
I doubt you will find an interesting article specifically about using mySql in an MVC application, but there must be a lot of stuff about mySQL in .NET in general.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC doesn't imply any data access mechanism, you can use ADO.NET, LINQ-2-SQL, Entity Framework or open-source ORM frameworks like NHibernate, SubSonic etc. with MVC apps.  The good news is that most data access libraries/frameworks for .NET support MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Here is a list of articles.

http://asp.net-tutorials.com/mysql/getting-started/

http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/09/using-mysql-with-asp-net-2/

http://www.aspdev.org/asp.net/asp.net-mysql-connect/

http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003052201&page=1

Just google it and you'll find much more articles on this subject.